# Settings sync -- settings.json is different between WSL and Windows on same machine yet same file gets synced

Tags: visual-studio-code

Following the method provided in the official documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync), I turned on sync for [Keyboard Shortcuts] `keybindings.json`, [User Snippets] `cpp.json` and [Settings] `settings.json`.

While VSCode Windows and VSCode on WSL on the same machine share the common `keybindings.json` and `cpp.json` files, WSL and Windows do not share the same `settings.json` file. The Windows version resides as:

`C:\Users\Tryer\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

and the WSL version resides as

`\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\Tryer\.vscode-server\data\Machine\settings.json`.

These are two different files. When I open `code .` from within WSL, and issue command `Settings Sync: Show Synced Data`, clicking on the `settings.json` file picks up the Windows version `C:\Users\Tryer\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`.

How does one resolve this conflict surrounding which `settings.json` file is synced on the same machine that runs both Windows and WSL?